# Possible overflow on sscanf

Tags: c++, c

me and my friend lately debated on whether the following could potentially trigger buffer overflow.

I am familiar with common 'sscanf' functions that I've come across. But this one seems a little bit wired to me because I am not so sure how to interpret format specifier '%' INT64_FMT in this case, and what 'sscanf' will write to bot 'first' & 'second' variable.

Any one has idea?

```
static int hKCMF_SLC(const char *content, int64_t *first, int64_t *second)
{
 return sscanf(content, "Size=%" INT64_FMT "-%" INT64_FMT, first, second);
}
```

Comment: I found this definition for `INT64_FNT`: `#ifdef unix
#define INT64_FMT "%lld"
#else
#define INT64_FMT "%I64d"
#endif`

Comment: What is C++-ish about that?

Comment: @Solkar: It's a valid function in C++ too?

Answer (score 6):

### Generally speaking:

When trying to write portable code, the format specifier for an `int64_t` can be different on different platforms. An int64_t might be a `typedef` for a number of types, including `int`, `long` or `long long`.

To get around this problem, we create macros that contain the correct format specifier. In recent versions of the C and C++ standards, you can use `inttypes.h` to get these macros. But for earlier systems, people needed to do this by hand.

So `INT64_FMT` is probably defined as something like:

```
#define INT64_FMT "lld"
```

Which would make the function call be (after preprocessing):

```
 return sscanf(content, "Size=%" "lld" "-%" "lld", first, second);
```

We can merge neighboring string literals into one string literal as well:

```
 return sscanf(content, "Size=%lld-%lld", first, second);
```

### About your code:

Let's make some assumptions:

1. `content` points to a null terminated string.
2. `first` points to an `int64_t`.
3. `second` points to an `int64_t`.
4. `INT64_FMT` is a macro that has the same value as `SCNi64` from `inttypes.h`.

Then there will be no buffer overflow.

Therefore, if the input is something like `"Size=4-3"`, then we will store `4` in `first` and `3` in `second`.

### Finally:

Generally, a buffer overflow occurs from writing past the end of an array. You're not actually writing to any arrays here, so a buffer overflow shouldn't occur.

Other errors (segmentation fault, stack overflow) could certainly occur if the assumptions are not held.

Comment: Additionally, if `content` doesn't point to a null-terminated string, you can get a segmentation fault, but not a buffer overflow.

Comment: @Brian “buffer overflow” is an ambiguous term that can be used to designate what happens if `content` is not null-terminated. For instance, Heartbleed has been called a “buffer overflow̦” (http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/04/08/anatomy-of-a-data-leak-bug-openssl-heartbleed/ )

Comment: Thanks @sharth. Now your last statement "Other errors (seg fault, stack over.." gets me thinking 'how exactly?'.

 Regardless of null-terminated or not, wouldn't sscanf reads 2 values and throw them in corresponding 'first' and 'second'?

Comment: @Arean: You missed the key part, "if the assumptions are not held". So if you passed a null pointer in as `first`, bad things will happen. Additionally, the stack has a finite maximum size. Calling `sscanf` could be the straw that breaks the camel's back. (It probably won't be).